# Why does candump of can-utils flag sent frames as RX instead of TX?

Tags: can-bus, socketcan, canutils

**raspberry pi** sends messages:

On that device I have two terminals open:

1. to look at `candump -x any` expecting TX messages
2. to send messages `cansend can0 <ID>#<data>`

**device B** receives the messages sent by **raspberry pi**.

However,  **raspberry pi** displays the "RX" flag, even though socketcan is setup explicitly with `loopback off`.

The candump on the TX side is malicious:
[image]

The frame counters increase correctly:
[image]
I am confident the "TX" messages are falsely displayed with "RX" flag.

Did anybody else experience that bug or knows what the issue is?

I worked with `candump` of the `can-utils` toolbox two weeks ago and it worked fine. I did not update the toolbox since then.

When I turned `loopback on`, I received two messages with RX

- one for the sent message
- one for the received message

I rebooted both systems, reinstalled `can-utils` and still receive the same behavior.